# Bootstrap CSS is not working on javaScript created Elements

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I created Bootstrap Modal using JavaScript and used proper classes mentioned in the bootstrap docs but It's not affecting the javaScript created elements.

I added classes and attributes of bootstrap using "classList.add()" and "setAttribute()" method but It's not affecting the DOM elements.

and   tags are added properly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" integrity="sha512-JQksK36WdRekVrvdxNyV3B0Q1huqbTkIQNbz1dlcFVgNynEMRl0F8OSqOGdVppLUDIvsOejhr/W5L3G/b3J+8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer integrity="sha512-1/RvZTcCDEUjY/CypiMz+iqqtaoQfAITmNSJY17Myp4Ms5mdxPS5UV7iOfdZoxcGhzFbOm6sntTKJppjvuhg4g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="./index.js" defer type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="Open" class="block">
            <h2 class="block-heading">Open</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="In-Progress" class="block">
            <h2 class="block-heading">In Progress</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="In-Review" class="block">
            <h2 class="block-heading">In Review</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="Done" class="block">
            <h2 class="block-heading">Done</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div type="button" id="addTask" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is JavaScript Code-

```
export default function example() {
    console.log("Working");  // To check func is working properly.

    // Create the modal element
    const modal = document.createElement("div");
    modal.classList.add("modal");
    modal.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
    // modal.setAttribute("role", "dialog");

    // Create the modal dialog element
    const modalDialog = document.createElement("div");
    modalDialog.classList.add("modal-dialog");
    // modalDialog.classList.add("modal-sm");
    modal.appendChild(modalDialog);

    // Create the modal content element
    const modalContent = document.createElement("div");
    modalContent.classList.add("modal-content");
    modalDialog.appendChild(modalContent);

    // Create the modal header element
    const modalHeader = document.createElement("div");
    modalHeader.classList.add("modal-header");
    modalContent.appendChild(modalHeader);

    // Create the close button and add it to the header
    const closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    closeButton.classList.add("btn-close");
    closeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    closeButton.setAttribute("data-bs-dismiss", "modal");
    closeButton.setAttribute("aria-label", "close");
    // closeButton.innerHTML = "&times;";
    modalHeader.appendChild(closeButton);

    // Create the modal title and add it to the header
    const modalTitle = document.createElement("h4");
    modalTitle.classList.add("modal-title");
    modalTitle.innerHTML = "Modal Header";
    modalHeader.appendChild(modalTitle);

    // Create the modal body element
    const modalBody = document.createElement("div");
    modalBody.classList.add("modal-body");
    modalContent.appendChild(modalBody);

    // Add content to the modal body
    const modalBodyContent = document.createElement("p");
    modalBodyContent.innerHTML = "This is a small modal.";
    modalBody.appendChild(modalBodyContent);

    // Create the modal footer element
    const modalFooter = document.createElement("div");
    modalFooter.classList.add("modal-footer");
    modalContent.appendChild(modalFooter);

    // Create the close button and add it to the footer
    const closeButton2 = document.createElement("button");
    closeButton2.classList.add("btn");
    closeButton2.classList.add("btn-secondary");
    closeButton2.setAttribute("type", "button");
    closeButton2.setAttribute("data-bs-dismiss", "modal");
    closeButton2.innerHTML = "Close";

    const saveButton = document.createElement("button");
    saveButton.classList.add("btn-primary");
    saveButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    saveButton.setAttribute("data-bs-dismiss", "modal");
    saveButton.classList.add("btn");
    saveButton.innerHTML = "Save";
    
    modalFooter.appendChild(closeButton2);
    modalFooter.appendChild(saveButton);


    // Append the modal to the body of the page
    document.body.appendChild(modal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `bootstrap-grid` in your css link tag, you might want to rename it to `bootstrap` wherein you can find the class you want to use.